# Can't seem to replicate permalink structure for localhost development site

Tags: posts, permalinks, database

I'm helping a friend migrate her WordPress powered shop. I'm to the part where I manually re enter all of her products on WooCommerce. On her current live site the link looks like:

`?product=yonce-tee`

And I can see on her permalink control panel that only the default settings have been used. So I go into my localhost permalink control panel and select the same settings(default and default), input the same exact product with the same settings, publish it and this is what my permalinks look like:

```
?product=yonce-tee-24
```

Ideally the links to the products stay exactly the same, but as you can see, '-24' has been appended to the permalink.

How can I replicate her site links exactly? I've tried messing around with the permalink settings for a bit, but can't get that -24 removed.

Comment: Check that the permalink for the younce-tee is younce-tee and not younce-tee-24, as if there are multiple products with the same name, wordpress appends a number to differentiate them authomatically...

Comment: *I'm to the part where I manually re enter all of her products on WooCommerce.* Why are you manually re-entering data and not just using the existing database? This will take all of 5 minutes to do if you follow the [instructions for Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_to_a_New_Server).

Comment: @Milo, I'm switching themes here. I've already 'moved wordpress'. The new theme has table data that is overwritten if I reinstall a backup database - so I believe the safest way to do this is by hand, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gloria - so it appends a random integer between 1 - 99 ? I don't understand why it would pick 24 otherwise

Comment: import the database, then switch themes

Comment: @Milo I've tried both orders - since they're using the same tables to store data either the products(which are just glorified wp_posts tables) get partially overwritten or my theme gets partially overwritten. I understand this is not typical behavior for a theme. Contacted the theme dev about this who basically responded with "yeah it's weird that our theme does that. too bad though" Themeforest. Very frustrating.